# Android Send SMS automatically when it is received

Tags: android, sms, send

I am developing an App which send a SMS to a site when you receive one SMS previously. My problem is when I try to send several SMSs form previously received SMSs...I would need to make a loop to control an array of strings (msisdn, texto) to check how many SMS I have received meanwhile I send them, one per one. Can someone help me? Thanks :)

```
public class GetSMSTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Context mContext;

public GetSMSTask(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

private static final String SMSBROKER = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/smsbroker/{params}";


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    OutcomeSms os=new OutcomeSms();
    String texto = null;
    String msisdn = null;

    HashMap<String, List<String>> hash = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();




    try {
        org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(SMSBROKER);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        Log.w("PlaySMSBroker","postSingal Response: " + response.getStatusLine());

        os.sendSMSMessage(msisdn, texto, mContext);

        list.add(texto);
        hash.put(msisdn,list);

        List<String> listOfMessages = hash.get(msisdn);
        int numberOfMessages = listOfMessages.size();

        for (int i=1; i<numberOfMessages; i++){
            os.sendSMSMessage(msisdn, texto, mContext);         
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("PlaySMSBroker", "UnsupportedEncodingException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("PlaySMSBroker", "ClientProtocolException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PlaySMSBroker", "IOException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("PlaySMSBroker", "Exception" + e.getClass().toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a HashMap to substitute your matrix of numbers and mensages.

Use the telefone number to the hashmap key and a list of strings to the hasmap value.

```
HashMap<a, b> matrix = new HashMap<a, b>();
```

a = telefone number

b = sended messages list

When you send an sms, add an entry to the list. If it is the first sms make a put in the hashmap.

To check how many SMSs you sended, get the list by the number and count how many  items you have in the list.

Example:

```
//to insert
HashMap<String, List<String>> hash = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("message1");
hash.put("993739292",list);

//to get list by telefone number
List<String> listOfMessages = hash.get("993739292");
int numberOfMessages = listOfMessages.size();
```

Comment: No.. this always return 1. You cant create a new list always when you send a new message. You need to re-use the existing list and hashmap.

Comment: please, copy my code and fix the problem...I dont know how to do that

Comment: it's impossible. you need to create the hashmap in a static way when you send the first message to a number.

Comment: I cant show you more code. Find about creating and using static variables in Java and put this List and HashMap in your main activity. Then change/update the variables in your asynctask.